# WCHAR wszFoo[CONSTANT_BAR] = {0}; <-- What does {0} mean?

Tags: c++

```
WCHAR wszFoo[CONSTANT_BAR] = {0};
```

I've never seen something like {0} used in C++ as part of the language.  And I have no idea how to search for a question like this online.  What is it?

Comment: This is why I absolutely **hate** that people do this. If you want something zero initialized, use a call to `memset` (or `ZeroMemory` or `SecureZeroMemory`), or an *empty* set of brackets. Adding the extra zero only leads to confusion. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$8.5.1/7 -

> "If there are fewer initializers in
>   the list than there are members in the
>   aggregate, then each member not
>   explicitly initialized shall be
>   value-initialized (8.5)."

All this means, is that there is an explict request to initialize first element to 0. Since initializers are not specified for the remaining elements, they are value-initialized. **This in case of WCHARs means are initialized to 0.**

What does value initialized means? Here is what the Standard says in $8.5 (italics are mine)

> To value-initialize an object of type
>   T means:
>
> — if T is a class type
>   (clause 9) with a user-declared
>   constructor (12.1), then the default
>   constructor for T is called (and the
>   initialization is ill-formed if T has
>   no accessible default constructor);
>
> —
>   if T is a non-union class type without
>   a user-declared constructor, then
>   every non-static data member and
>   base-class component of T is
>   value-initialized;
>
> — if T is an array
>   type, then each element is
>   value-initialized;
>
> — otherwise, the
>   object is zero-initialized *<------
>   WCHAR will fit here*
>
> To zero-initialize an object of type T
>   means:
>
> — if T is a scalar type (3.9),
>   the object is set to the value of 0
>   (zero) converted to T; *<------ WCHAR
>   will fit here*
>
> — if T is a non-union
>   class type, each nonstatic data member
>   and each base-class subobject is
>   zeroinitialized;
>
> — if T is a union
>   type, the object’s first named data
>   member89) is zero-initialized;
>
> — if T
>   is an array type, each element is
>   zero-initialized;
>
> — if T is a
>   reference type, no initialization is
>   performed.

Comment: Thanks!  As I read other answers, I wondered, "Well, then what happens if it's an array of classes?"  So you win, because you answered that, too :)

Answer (score 6):

See [array initialization.](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/array-initialization.html)

> **Missing initialization values use zero**
>
> If an explicit array size is
>   specified, but an shorter
>   initiliazation list is specified, the
>   unspecified elements are set to zero.
>
> `float pressure[10] = {2.101, 2.32,
>   1.44};`
>
> This not only initializes the first
>   three values, but all remaining
>   elements are set to 0.0. *To initialize
>   an array to all zeros, initialize only
>   the first value.*

Comment: Aha! It never occurred to me that that was initializing an array.  I would have known right away if a comma had been involved, but {0} usually means something completely different in other contents (e.g. C# String.Format())

Answer (score 3):

It's initializing an array.

```
float p1[1000];         // No intitialization.
float p2[1000] = {0.0}; // All 1000 values initialized to zero.
```

More here: [C++ Notes: Array Initialization](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/array-initialization.html)

Answer (score 2):

It means initialize all elements of `wszFoo` to zero.